# Maximizing a unique trace quadratic form

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I am dealing with an unsupervised problem where I have ended up with the following maximization problem:

$\max_{C\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}}\sum_{i=0}^{m} tr(CA^ixx^\top A^{i^\top}C^\top) \\ \mathrm{subject \;to} \; ||C||_2 \leq c$

where $A \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are a known matrix and vector, respectively. The constant $c$ is a bound on the maximum singular value of $C$ (this is not a strict condition and it could take a different form, I just realize that if I don't have a constraint on the size of $C$, then the solution is to produce a $C$ that gives the objective function a value of $\infty$). My matrix algebra is failing me in producing a solution to this problem. I've tried forming the dual problem by adding the Lagrangian from the constraint and taking derivatives, however I cannot seem to solve the problem (I end up with what should be a bunch of rank-3 tensors, making the problem difficult. If someone could find a nice solution to this problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This is a textbook quadratic optimization problem: just view $C$ as a $pn$ vector.

Comment: Even with the sum in front, this is textbook? I really haven't figured out how to deal with it appropriately. I do know how to show that the eigenvectors of $A^ixx^\top A^{i^{\top}}$ are the maximizers when there is no sum involved.

Comment: Yes, even with the sum: you're adding up $m+1$ quadratic forms, which yields a single quadratic form.  Write it out for simple cases such as $p=1$ and $n=2$ to see what's going on if you're unsure.

Comment: Gonna try that out and see, and hopefully can extend to the case where C is pxn and the trace actually matters. thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Have you noticed that $M=\sum_i A^{i}xx^\prime{A^{i}}^\prime$ is just a known $n\times n$ matrix? Your objective function therefore is $$\operatorname{tr}(CMC^\prime)=\sum_{i,j,k}C_{ij}M_{jk}C_{ik}=\sum_{j,k} M_{jk}(CC^\prime)_{jk}.$$

Comment: @whuber I did! your comments really helped me out a lot. thanks so much. I will be adding my detailed answer for future visitors in a bit